# Webcam Does Not Turn Off When Leaving React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webrtc, webcam, getusermedia

I am currently taking pictures from my webcam in a React App. When I leave the component however, the green light continues to stay on and I do not seem able to close my webcam. Here is the code I use to use the webcam.

```
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    window.localstream = stream;
    video.play();
  }, function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  })
```

Later, in my componentWillUnmount lifecycle handler, I run the following code:

```
video.pause();
video.srcObject = null;
window.localstream.getTracks()[0].stop();
var list = document.getElementById("video"); 
list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0])
```

My webcam does not turn off however when I console.log the MediaStreamTrack's readyState = "ended" and enabled is equal to false. Is there any way I can force my webcam to turn off?

Comment: Does it work outside the context of React?

Comment: Have you tried `window.localstream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())` to be sure all the tracks are stoped? That command should be the only you need to run to close the webcam.

Comment: I tried that but it would not work. I ended up just using an <a> to go to a new page.

Answer (score 1):

React provide you such amazing hooks as [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) and others. All you need to do is to stop video tracks while leaving the page or closing the component.

```
useEffect(() => {
  /*
   * action on opening page:
   * as example you could get all video devices and
   * to choose which camera exactly you want to use
   */
  getDevices()
  return () => {
    stopVideo();
  };
}, []);
```

As we have *return* statement in useEffect hook, the function *stopVideo()* will be called each time we leave the page.

Now let's suppose that you store in state current video track

```
const [videoStream, setVideoStream] = useState<MediaStream>();
```

Then function to stop videostream will looks like:

```
function stopVideo() {
   if (videoStream) {
     videoStream.getTracks().forEach((track: any) => {
       if (track.readyState === "live") {
         track.stop();
       }
     });
   }
 }
```

[see in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/turn-off-camera-rdegvw?file=/src/App.tsx)

**Brief**: to turn of your camera you have to stop tracks, so If you'll add to your project useEffect as shown below, it will help you achieve your goal.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let videoElement: HTMLVideoElement | undefined

    if (videoRef.current) {
      videoElement = videoRef.current
    }

    return () => {
      if (videoElement && videoElement.srcObject) {
        (videoElement.srcObject as MediaStream).getTracks().forEach((track: any) => {
          if (track.readyState == 'live') {
            track.stop()
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }, [videoRef])
```

Comment: In my code storing the MediaStream in a *state* will cause the camera to never stop - even though tracks a are being stopped.